# Highcharts: On setExtremes the xAxis overflowing the chart plot area

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a very annoying issue... when I use the xAxis.setExtremes the chart line sometimes starts earlier than the plot area... actually where the Y axis labels are

[image: Chart overflowing]

noticed it happens only when the chart gets initiated  on the fly (by code and resized to the parent container)...

so to give you the context

I have a page with two tabs.... first tab is opened by default, the content of the second tab is obviously hidden... the chart is there...

so the chart gets initiated on a container that has display: none.... that means when I click on the tab...the chart width is set to default and not to the container's width....

to solve this issue, I use:

```
this.chartInstance.setSize(containerWidth);
this.chartInstance.reflow();
```

when I open the tab... which helps resize the chart correctlyto the container's width after the container actually gets displayed (display: block).

After, all works fine.... except that when I set the extremes, sometimes it overflows...

this DOESN'T happen, when I initialize the chart normally (on a container that is shown from the start) - in my case, when the second tab (the one with the chart) is selected by default... so the container is set to display: block from the start.

Comment: On which axis you are setting extremes

Comment: as stating in the first paragraph (and the subject ;) ), xAxis

Comment: Please recreate the problem in a live demo, like JSFiddle. What wrappers and what version of Highcharts are you using? Maybe the problem is resolved already in the current version - 5.0.10.